# Start new Activity outside the Activity context.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-activity, runtime-error

I tried to start an `Activity` and close other in my `AsyncTask` class (`onPostExecute()`).

My code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(parentActivity, ThunderHunter.class);
c.startActivity(i);
parentActivity.finish();
```

But it doesn't work, logcat shows :

```
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1029)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1023)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:283)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at com.radzik.thunter.FunkcjeAPI$Logowanie.onPostExecute(FunkcjeAPI.java:151)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at com.radzik.thunter.FunkcjeAPI$Logowanie.onPostExecute(FunkcjeAPI.java:1)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-01 18:01:27.640: E/AndroidRuntime(12398):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I changed code to that :

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ThunderHunter.class);
c.startActivity(i);
parentActivity.finish();
```

But without excepted results (still same error).

Is there any way to that properly ?

Comment: context mean from wich activity you want to call the new one, so try this Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this(or getApplicationContext()), ThunderHunter.class);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The logcat tells you what the problem is in the first line

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag
```

add that flag

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ThunderHunter.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
c.startActivity(i);
parentActivity.finish();
```

You can get a list of all available `Intent Flags` [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Why do you need to use this Flag doc says: "If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack." So The problem actualy in using not Activity Context.

Comment: @YevgenKulik depending on the situation, that might be the issue. But there are times when `Activity Context` is not available.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` will solve your error, but make sure if you need this flag or not as it will trigger the activity as new task which you may not want in your scenario.

In order to avoid this flag, you can write a `Handler` in main `Activity` and call it in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: can you give a more complete example of this ?

Answer (score 2):

try this-

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ThunderHunter.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
parentActivity.finish();
```

You are calling new activity outside the activity context, so you have to set the flag and pass the context outside the activity.