# Use of android taskaffinity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am reading about taskaffinity & created a demo app with following Activities :

- A
- B ===> taskaffinity, com.ando
- C
- D ===> taskaffinity, com.ando
- E

It is written that, Activities with same taskaffinity secretly opens the single instance of another one.

So, I put log in onResume of every activity to see task id. If it creates single instance then why its not executing onResume of B when I open D and vice-versa.

I read developers site and other post but still not got how to use taskaffinity and whats its use, why we should'tn use singleInstance instead ?

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.danroid.taskaffinity.A"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- android:taskAffinity="com.ando" -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.danroid.taskaffinity.B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:taskAffinity="@string/task_affinity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.danroid.taskaffinity.C"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.danroid.taskaffinity.D"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:taskAffinity="@string/task_affinity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.danroid.taskaffinity.E"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please post your manifest. It isn't clear what `launchMode`s you are using.

Comment: @DavidWasser I did't defined any launch mode.

Comment: How are you getting the task ID?

Comment: Please post your manifest so we can see the whole thing.

Comment: @DavidWasser I added manifest ,I used this.getTaskId() to get task ID.

Comment: And what is the package name?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you call `startActivity()` to transition from one `Activity` to another, if you do not set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the `Intent` flags, the new `Activity` will be started in the same task, regardless of the value of `taskAffinity`.

However, if you set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in the `Intent` flags, the new `Activity` will **still** be started in the same task **if the new `Activity` has the same `taskAffinity` as the `taskAffinity` of the task (this is determined by the `taskAffinity` of the root `Activity` in the task).** But, if the new `Activity` has a different `taskAffinity`, the new `Activity` will be started in a new task.

Based on your description, if you don't set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when starting a new `Activity`, then all of your activities will end up in the same task.

Comment: If I want to start an Activity of another application and I want that activity on the same task.! How can achieve this.? If I don't use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, the I got this exception :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999152/start-new-activity-outside-the-activity-context/17999248.  Thank you for you suggestion in advance.

Comment: @VatsalPatel The exception is because you are trying to start an `Activity` from a non-Activity context (ie: you are in a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`). In that case, there is no "same task". Only activities exist in a task. Other components do not. Please open a new question to solve your problem. Asking in a comment isn't helpful and won't get you the attention you may need.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. but I got the answer from your another post :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833402/difference-between-intent-flag-activity-clear-task-and-intent-flag-activity-task/29565717#29565717    Really helpful information.