# Cannot finish Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

In my app I have 5 activities excluding main activity Im using other 4 activites repeatedly in cycle manner.

in my each activity (except main) onPause() method I have written Activityname.this.finish();

when I'm ending cycle on 5 th activity and returning back to main activity...

but my problem is when I'm ending main activity.. instead of closing app, it goes to 3 rd activity.

I don't know where is a problem exactly. may be in 3rd activity im using db n not closing it explicitly. Is this a problem?

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    PlayerDetails.this.finish();
}
```

this onPause() method I'm using

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alert.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        alert.setMessage("Really Exit?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    }
        });
        try{
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is my mainActivity method to close the app

Comment: Can you please put down some code snippets?

Comment: try giving us some code  and check in the button (Exit) in your main activity , does that button definition contain any intent link to 3rd activity ? or just simple system.kill or finish() or android.process.os.kill(android.process.os.kill.mypid) [take these as pseudo , search for correct format my bad i don't remember it right now]

Comment: @akshaybhanage just call finish(); when you start the next activity but don't call it when you go from main to any activity

Comment: just finish() the existing activity Whenever ur moving from one activity to other activity

Comment: yes I'm using that. but why it is going to 3rd activity on ending mainActivity

Comment: This happens only when u have not finished the previous activity after moving to next activity. please check again

Comment: also u can use `PlayerDetails.finish();` instead of ` PlayerDetails.this.finish();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) instead of calling `finish()` every time in each Activity. When you start a new Activity just use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` followed by `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` with the `Intent` which will clear the stack buffer and start the activity as a new. something like ..

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(current_context, destination_activity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
```

You can find more information about Flags in this [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833402/difference-between-intent-flag-activity-clear-task-and-intent-flag-activity-task).

Answer (score 1):

Use onStop() override method instead of using onPause(), due to some reason onPause may not be call but onStop will.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onPause();
     finish();
}
```