# Android app crashes with use of a "back" button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to go back to the main menu once a user dies using a **back** button.

```
if(gameOver) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | 
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

The above code brings me back to the main menu, I can replay the game. But if the user dies again and goes back to the main menu for now the second time, the entire app gets an error message saying :

> **android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference**

It there was something wrong with my if statement I could understand, but the thing is the statement works once but never again. I'm just really confused.

Comment: This answer here has a great detailed explanation of how `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` works. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29565717/11040422