# Handling backpress on activity

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, android-activity, dialog

I have 2 activity called Login and Main in login activity there is code block that makes this functionality that if I click back in Main activity it will close the app instead of  going back to login activity but I want to handle back press and maybe with one dialog "you are going to exit the app you sure? "  or something like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

this code block is in my login actvity

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833402/difference-between-intent-flag-activity-clear-task-and-intent-flag-activity-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy and paste the below code in your onBackPressed() method in MainActivity.java.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Confirm close")
            .setMessage("Are you sure want to close app")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which {
                    finish();
                }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which {
                   dialog.dismiss();
                 }
             }).create().show();
```

Comment: that's what I've been looking for  thanks.Thanks for answer

Comment: I tried your solution but it gave me this error

E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.rtets.ui.activities.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@ec13922[MainActivity] that was originally added here

Comment: @muhammedlevent you are from LoginActivity to MainActivity so the Builder should be placed in LoginActivity.java  and  use new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity .this).xxxx  ??

Answer (score 1):

You can handle in onBackPressed if user is logged in :

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(!user.isLoggedIn()){
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }else{
            //Show alert
        }
    }
```