# android start activity from background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, background-process

My app creates a timer task (background thread) and periodically need to display something. Main screen maybe hidden later by other apps. I found out (AFAIRemember on stackoverflow) that for making toast notification I need to use `runOnUiThread` `runnable`(just `Toast.makeText` crashed the app).

Now I want my background thread to be able to collect user input. I created activity class with layout and call it via intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, screen2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

When main screen is active, my new screen shows fine. But when main screen hidden, my other screen is hidden and I see it only when I make my app active again via Recents button.

I tried to run intent for second screen via `runOnUiThread` `runnable` - same result - new screen hidden until my app is active.

How can background thread display some activity on screen (UI thread)?

P.S.

`Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivity(takePictureIntent);` 
- displayes camera screen hidden, whereas action call below bring call screen on top of other app currently on screen

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("+79851559700")));

        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        callIntent.setPackage("com.android.phone");
        try {
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Adding `Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` to camera intent made camera screen display from background timer tast, however it did not made my activity to do it.

Changing to `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);` made second screen appear on foreground however somehow it replaced main screen.

Comment: dont use `Timer` / `TimerTask` combo, use `Handler`s instead

Comment: My advice is adding Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); but you already tried it. But what I understand is that your problem is not only showing an activty from backgorund thread, you want to show more than one activiy, am I right?

Comment: @ondermerol, main activity starts background thread by timertask, then it's also go background, timer thread needs to start other activity for showing and gaining some user input. As of now I see I will need two applications (one separate just to display UI screen via intent)... Why can't I have two activities in one app...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374610/use-of-android-taskaffinity
setting in manifest taskaffinity for second activity fixed my issue. Now I have in main activity method onActivityResult is run BEFORE startActivityForResult. What is it - glitch?