# android startActivityForResult from background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, startactivityforresult

This question arose from no answers to my question:
 [android start activity from background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328894/android-start-activity-from-background-thread)

From my efforts on the issue I now think there is no way for background thread to do startActivityForResult for user input and get results (e.g. by onActivityResult). Please confrirm that it is now not possible by known means or advice on workaround (or Android versions where it works, I tried on 4x). Details of options I investigated below:

My main activity starts background thread via timertask and later is moved to background by user starting other apps. Then background timertask thread tries e.g.:

```
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        //takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //startActivity(takePictureIntent);
    }
```

If code is as above with `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` commented, camera starts on background in main activity stack level. If `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` is uncommented, camera starts in foreground, however, in main activity `onActivityResult` is invoked right after I call `startActivityForResult` without waiting for camera to take picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `runOnUiThread` to execute your code in main thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: tried that already for other intent, tried right now for MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - camera is not seen on screen.

Comment: What is your issue now?